# Example of a non finitely generated module such that Hom doesn't preserve coproducts.

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I'm looking for an example of a non finitely generated module such that the $\operatorname{Hom}$ functor doesn't preserve coproducts and an explanation as to why.

Thanks!

Comment: For the interested readers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59282/sums-compact-objects-f-g-objects-in-categories-of-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* For an infinite set $I$ and a non-trivial module $X$, consider the $I$-fold coproduct $X^{(I)}$: Its covariant Hom-functor $\text{Hom}(X^{(I)},-)$ does not perserve coproducts. For the proof, look at $\text{id}\in\text{Hom}(X^{(I)}, X^{(I)})$.